# Adding Google Remarketing Script tags to Drupal 7 website

Tags: 7

I need to find a way to easily add google remarketing script tags to my Drupal 7 website. If there is a module that can do this easier and faster then that's what I need.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the [Google Adwords Remarketing](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_adwords_remarketing) module. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Adds the [Google Adwords Remarketing web statistics tracking system](http://adwords.google.com/support/aw/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=27765) to your website.
>
> NB - Google now has another (easier) method for using Remarketing tags. If your Adwords account is linked to your Google Analytics account you can enable the tag by installing the [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module and ticking a tick box under the Google Analytics Drupal admin page - see attached image.
>
> This tick box causes a slight alteration in the GA tag which is needed by Google Remarketing.