# Is there an easy way to include a Facebook remarketing tag in my D7 site?

Tags: 7, social-network, javascript

[Adding Google Remarketing Script tags to Drupal 7 website](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/89987/adding-google-remarketing-script-tags-to-drupal-7-website) shows how to add a Google remarketing tag using a module. Is there a similar solution for adding a Facebook remarketing tag easily?

I would use the `drupal_add_js` hook if that were so easy, but the issue is that the remarketing tag also includes an `<img/>` element (the pixel) in a `<noscript>` tag, so I can't include that easily in the same hook.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be very simple. All I had to do was paste the code into the `<head>` part of html.tpl.php from within the /templates/ folder.

Comment: Just where you want in the header tag? above all header-tag content?

Comment: I don't think it matters where in the header tag; I put it near the bottom.

Comment: By "Header" you meant the head tag yes? (Just to make sure it's not a HTML5 header tag).

Comment: @benos Ah you're correct - I mean the head tag. Editing my answer.